# Fb login using extension

Tags: fbloginview

What should be the app domain in FB app option in Fb Login when my app is a chrome extension.
I have tried chrome-extension:/[id]
without it the error is coming

`Can't Load URL: The domain of this URL isn't included in the app's domains. To be able to load this URL, add all domains and subdomains of your app to the App Domains field in your app settings.`

This is my logic.js

```
    window.fbAsyncInit = function() {
    FB.init({
      appId      : '1232048723506658',
      xfbml      : true,
      version    : 'v2.6'
    });
    FB.getLoginStatus(function(response) {

  if (response.status === 'connected') {
    console.log('Logged in.');
  }
  else {
    console.log('initiate FB login...');
    FB.login();
  }
});
    };  

  (function(d, s, id){
     var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
     if (d.getElementById(id)) {return;}
     js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id;
     js.src = "https://connect.facebook.net/en_US/sdk.js";
     fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
   }(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));
```

Please explain .